# How to add current hour and minutes to inserted date

Tags: oracle

I'm inserting data into table with date value, how to add to inserting date value current system time in format HH:MM

My insert

```
INSERT INTO tab1 VALUES to_date('11-OCT-2021');
```

I wanna insert '11-OCT-2021 22:08' where 22:08 current system time. How to do it

Thx

Comment: Since Oracle have no time datatype you need to answer two questions: 1) How to get current hour and minute from current date as string? 2) How to concatenate two strings of date parts and convert it into date? Which of them is an issue?

Comment: No problem, I can do it  in source script (date + current time), and insert it with format to_date( date+time, 'MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI')  but I try to found way to do it by oracle tools to avoid change script

Comment: What does "by Oracle tools" mean? SQL is a language where you write some query. It has no tools and of course you cannot change something without actual change. By default `to_date` fills missing components with their initial values which are the beginning of existing part: quarter, month, day, hour, minute.

Comment: Thx for you answer but it's not a philosophy discussion

Comment: It's not a philosophy, use concatenation and `to_date`. But you didn't describe what is wrong with it in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```sql
INSERT INTO tab1 (column_name)
  VALUES ( DATE '2021-10-11' + (SYSDATE - TRUNC(SYSDATE)) );
```

or

```sql
INSERT INTO tab1 (column_name)
VALUES (
  TO_DATE(
    '11-OCT-2021' || TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'HH24:MI:SS'),
    'DD-MON-YYYYHH24:MI:SS',
    'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=American'
  )
);
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=007897daabc9949fb41b603fbd097c5d)*

Answer (score 1):

Here's one option:

```
SQL> create table tab1 (datum date);

Table created.

SQL> insert into tab1 values (date '2021-10-11');

1 row created.

SQL> select * from tab1;

DATUM
-------------------
11.10.2021 00:00:00

SQL> update tab1 set datum = to_date(to_char(datum, 'dd.mm.yyyy') || to_char(sysdate, 'hh24:mi'), 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi');

1 row updated.

SQL> select * from tab1;

DATUM
-------------------
11.10.2021 21:47:00

SQL>
```

---

On the other hand, why wouldn't you insert the "whole" value immediately?

```
SQL> rollback;

Rollback complete.

SQL> insert into tab1 values (sysdate);

1 row created.

SQL> select * from tab1;

DATUM
-------------------
12.10.2021 21:48:21

SQL>
```